# How can I reveal the real name of the users online (with university IDs)?

Tags: users, who

In the terminal, how can I reveal the real name of the users online (with university IDs)? getent?

Comment: This question is too vague and expects an implicit understanding of how the UNIX user information is stored in the askers specific circumstances.

Comment: I have already shown in the screen the users online at the university network (who | grep it214***) which represents informatics telematics students with registration number which begins with 214, and I'd like to reveal the normal name of each student online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools to allow you to do that. Try them all:

```
who
w
last -p now
finger
```

which one you prefer is up to you :-)

Comment: On which system does it work `last -p`? With GNU less (436 - 458 GNU less) works too `last | grep 'still logged ' ` that probably produces a similar output.

Comment: The above commands will only detail local users.   If getent is installed,   getent passwd <username> will return the full  passwd entry including the GECOS field.